# Private key of the certificate

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, certificate, x509certificate

I am connection to the server and after authenticate as a client

```
sslStream = new SslStream(_serverStream, false, SslCertificateValidatorCallback);
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(host);
```

I want to use recieved certificate as a server. Is it possible? For that I need private key, but this certificate doesn't have one.

So my questions are:
1. If I have certificate with public key, can I add private key to that certificate?
2. Can I create new certificate based on recieved with a public and private key?

Any ideas will be very helpful for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest doing some research on Certificate encryption / asymmetric encryption as your question demonstrates a lack of understanding in that area. Not trying to be rude, just saying.

In order to use a certificate as a server you must already posses the private key of the certificate.

In short:

1. Server is bound to port and posses a certificate with a public/private key pair
2. A request is made to the server
3. The client uses the certificate to validate the identity of the server
4. If valid communication continues
5. The public key is used to encrypt traffic to the server
6. The server uses its private key to decrypt traffic

It should be noted that the cert is generally only used to exchange a symmetric key (symmetric encryption is faster). So after the cert has been validated, a key exchange takes place, and communication resumes using the symmetric encryption key.

[Here is an article to get you started](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776447(v=ws.10).aspx) 
[And here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work)

To answer your questions specifically:
 1. No
 2. It is possible to 'spoof' the cert - however, this would be naughty, and most (good) clients would catch on and prevent any further traffic from taking place